# Disable Android Application through the certificate

Tags: android, certificate, app-manager

My company is letting an external provider manage its internal Android "app store" for it. For this, the provider wants a p12 and the APK.

My question is: would there still be an "emergency" way for us to disable an app?

I know that on iOS there is always the possibility of disabling a provisioning profile; is there something similar with this Android setup?

Thanks

Comment: You can use call API or use cloud messaging .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to be able to disable your application remotely ?
If so, there is no built-in way to do it, with or without using the signing certificate. Even removing it from the Play Store would not prevent existing users to use it, since you can't uninstall an app for users.

The only solution I see would be to introduce a custom check when the app is launched, which would call a webservice and depending of the "status" returned, start a blocking behavior in your app. However, this requires network, and it's not a very good usability best practice, since your users could see their service interrupted without warning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is what I expected, but I'm happy to have a confirmation.

Comment: Hi @Gary, thank you for your feedback. If this answer (or any other)  has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.